# Why does the graph of $ cos^{-1}(x)$ differ from the graph of the relation defined by the formula : $x= cos(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, soft-question, inverse

If I am corrrect, the equation  defining the inverse of a function $f$ can be found by switching $x$ and $y$.

Consequently, I expected  $x = cos(y)$ to have the same graph as $y=cos^{-1} (x)$.

How to explain it's not actually the case?

Which one qualifies as the inverse of the function $cos(x)$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer: $x=\cos{y}$ does not imply $y = \cos^{-1}(x)$, as surprising as it may sound. That's only one solution, there are infinitely many others.

Comment: The second graph is not that of a function: it obviously doesn’t pass the vertical line test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that $\cos^{-1}$, despite the name, is not the inverse of $\cos$. Remember, $\cos$ is not actually invertible, since $\cos$ is not one-to-one. The graph of $x = \cos(y)$ shows the curve failing the vertical line test, rather dramatically.

Instead, $\cos^{-1}$ is a *right-inverse* of $\cos$, meaning that $\cos(\cos^{-1}(x)) = x$ for all applicable $x$ (i.e. $x \in [-1, 1]$). On the other hand, it is not a left inverse, in the sense that it is not necessarily the case that $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. As a concrete example,
$$\cos^{-1}(\cos(2\pi)) = \cos^{-1}(1) = 0 \neq 2\pi.$$

The reflection rule applies to actual inverses, which need the function to be one-to-one (and onto, although you can always restrict the codomain to the range). One could say that $x = \cos(y)$, while it doesn't define a function of $y$ in terms of $x$, it is the inverse *relation* to $\cos$, which allows for a one-to-many relationship.